# How to create stackable responsive four column (1 row) grid with image in each and image is responsive?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**THE ISSUE**

I need to do something I thought would be fairly common, yet I've been unable to find any definitive answers on how to go about it. It might be that I don't know the correct terms to search for, such as what one calls it when rows in a column "stack" under each other responsively.

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE**

Have a row with four columns with min widths of say 200px, and width of 25% of parent container. The end result should always be horizontally centered (which I can't really show in my below examples, but I trust it's easy enough to imagine).

```
||  COL-1           |  COL-2           |  COL-3           |  COL-4           ||
```

Once the parent container is less than 991px, I want the columns to stack, in pairs. However, in most coding examples I've found online, typically what happens is this:

```
||  COL-1           |  COL-2           |  COL-3           |
|  COL-4           ||
```

What I need is that there's always an even number of rows, **and** the image inside each cell resize as the cells resize.

Such as:

```
COL-1           COL-2           COL-3           COL-4

or break-point 1 (contents centered)

COL-1           COL-2           
COL-3           COL-4

or break-point 2 (contents centered)

COL-1           
COL-2           
COL-3           
COL-4
```

**WHAT I'VE DONE SO FAR**

After much searching (had to get my search terms right!) I found [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54670754/1092677) of what I want to do, but there was only text in the boxes. Once I throw an image into the mix (one image per cell), two issues occur. 1) The images are not responsive in their size, and they should be. 2) Before the stacking goes to 2x2 it first goes to 1x3 + 1x1 (the same issue I show in my ascii layouts above).

I've set up a CodePen of the original code [here](https://codepen.io/inspiredearth/pen/PoGwXWG). It works just as I require, but not with images.

And there's a CodePen of my attempt to add in images [here](https://codepen.io/inspiredearth/pen/WNGbLGE).

**My attempted code is:**

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* mobile phone */
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1em;
}

.flex-item-1 {
  background: indianred;
}

.flex-item-2 {
  background: blue;
}

.flex-item-3 {
  background: tomato;
}

.flex-item-4 {
  background: coral;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

/* tablet */
@media screen and (min-width: 675px) and (max-width: 960px) {
  .flex-item {
    flex: 1 0 19em;
  }

  .flex-item:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-left: 1em;
  }
}

/* desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  .flex-item {
    flex: 1 0;
  }

  .flex-container > * + * {
    margin-left: 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item flex-item-1">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item flex-item-2">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item flex-item-3">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">
    </div>

    <div class="flex-item flex-item-4">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

(I can't figure out how to make the RESULT panel in Stackoverflow "Code Snippets" wide enough to see the stacking effect of this code, so the Codepen examples would need to be viewed to see that).

#### MY QUESTION

How can I get the intended outcome, of the image sizes also being responsive, down to a specified min-width limit (e.g., 200px), and the columns still stacking evening just as they do before the images were introduced into the code?

Comment: you can set the css like `img {
  width: 100%;
}`

Comment: @Jerry - Oh boy. I was obviously doing this too late at night. I **had** tried exactly that, but I now see I'd inadvertently put a `.` before my `img` selector in the CSS. So it had no effect, and I concluded I must need to do something completely different.